# What is the rationale behind "It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings"?

Tags: php, datetime

In python I can do

```
import datetime
print datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
# prints `2014-06-27`.
```

Similarly, in node.js:

```
console.log(new Date().toDateString());
// Fri Jun 27 2014
```

When I try the same in php:

```
<?php
print date('Y-m-d');
?>
```

I'm getting this

> Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in ....

What is the rationale behind this message? Why don't python or node bother? What exactly is "unsafe" about using the system timezone?

Since there are many posts regarding this error, **please read carefully** : I'm **not** asking **how** to fix it (pretty much obviously), I'm wondering **why** I'm getting this message in the first place.

Comment: If you have a time machine, you could nip [back to 2006 and ask Derick](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/2e9d063814886f2fd1399678713e54144641d0a6). It's the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through this thread

http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-internals/135qbh5twa/date-timezone-e-warning-really-necessary-whats-the-rationale

I understand that there are no valid technical reasons for this warning. The only reason is that someone from the php group thought it could be useful to reduce the number of bugreports on bugs.php.net. So, basically a `magic_quotes` kind of stuff.

Comment: I'm glad you eventually found a rationale that satisfied you.  I'm sorry I was unable to make my answer work for you.

Answer (score 3):

`PHP` is traditionally used for web development, so one plausible reason would be that the consumers of a web service would not be in the same time zone as the time zone that the server is hosted in, and presumably configured for (in terms of system time).

The warning makes sense in the context of users of a system seeing the correct time on the client side.

There is some discussion of this [here](http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-internals/135qbh5twa/date-timezone-e-warning-really-necessary-whats-the-rationale) which mentions the justification I gave above. Another justification from the same page, from someone who is presumably a PHP language developer.

> No - you, as an admin, are required to make an informed decision on
>   what you want your timezone to be. There have been way too many bug
>   reports where people had no clue, so now we throw a warning.

Comment: +1 I guess PHP needs to be made more "noob-safe" than other languages. Not that you won't have the same *issues* in other languages, just that PHP devs are probably more oblivious to it...

Comment: I don't understand the first part. Obviously, website visitors live in different timezones, how does this affect the timezone setting on the server? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @thg435, Suppose you let it default to the system local time for every request. In that case, any consumer of your web service would see your system's local time, which is probably not your intent.

Comment: @thg435, Instead, you would either decide that (a) Most of your customers live in time zone X and set your time to that time zone, or (b) Your customers are all over the place and you want to make some effort to detect where they are and set the timezone appropriately.

Comment: @merlin2011: ok, assume I choose the route (a) and reconfigure my server's tz. Normally, I'd use OS tools like `/etc/localtime` to do it system-wide. Why does php think it's "unsafe" to rely on that? There must be a reason!

Comment: I meant to set timezone in php not system wide.

Comment: @merlin2011: sorry, still doesn't make sense to me.